# capitalize each letter of word without javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've written this code to capitalize first letter of every word in a sentence without using javascript. just html and css. but it doesnt seem to be working. plz help my solve this problem. The first code is just a demo which works. But the second code is what actually I want to submit in my assignment, plz help me solve the problem.

code 1:

```
<html>
<head>

    <input type="text" size="60%" style="text-transform:capitalize">

</head>
</html>
```

code 2:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

    <style>
        h2{
            color:#0F0;
            font-size:large;
            font-weight:bold;
            font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive
        }

        p{
            color:#0F0;
            font-size:large;
            font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive
        }

        y{
            text-transform:capitalize;  
        }

    </style>


    <script language="javascript">

    function myFunction(){
        var a  = document.getElementById("input").value;
        document.getElementById("output").value = a;
    }

    </script>

</head>

<body>
<h1>Question 5</h1>
<center>

    <form name=frm1>

        <table border="2" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="5" style="background-color: blue"  width="50%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2"><h2>Capitalize First Letter Of Each Word</h2></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><p>Enter Text Here:</p></td>

                <td> <x> <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="text here" size="65%"> </x> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2"> <y> <input type="text" id="output" placeholder="Output" size="100%" readonly> </y> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>    

        <input type="button" value="click me" onClick="myFunction()">
    </form>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's with the <y> tag? Why not use a css class?!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code, as written, seems to be that you are using:

```
y { text-transform: capitalize; }
```

It works fine (see this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mifi79/A3Kqr/) if you instead target the #output element with:

```
#output { text-transform: capitalize; }
```

I'll let all the tables and strange non-semantic elements (, , etc.) slide since you are obviously in a class and learning ;-)

Comment: Glad to hear it, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following as reference.

```
<input  type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase">
```

Answer (score 0):

So why don't you use the method which is already working? change second textbox code to this

```
<input type="text" id="output" placeholder="Output" size="100%" readonly style="text-transform:capitalize">
```

Or else if you really want to use Internal Style Sheet then you can use id Selector. y is not an html element so you cannot use it as element selector. Better use id Selector as

```
    #output{
        text-transform:capitalize;  
    }
```

as Output is your id for textbox it will work.

Answer (score -4):

You can simply do:

```
var a  = document.getElementById("input").value;
document.getElementById("output").value = a;
document.getElementById("output").style.textTransform = "capitalize";
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JMc83/)

Comment: yaayy works! thanks :)

Comment: please read the question properly.